# Excel file not opening after completion of download?

Tags: c#, excel

By using the fallowing code I have exported the data table to excel .

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
string tab = string.Empty;

Response.Write("<font style='font-size:11.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");

Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");

Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-size:11.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");

foreach (DataColumn datacol in dt.Columns)
{
    Response.Write("<Td style = "+"\"width:120px;\""+">");
    Response.Write("<B>");
    Response.Write(tab + datacol.ColumnName);
    Response.Write("</B>");
    Response.Write("</Td>");
}
Response.Write("</TR>");

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    Response.Write("<TR>");
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Response.Write("<Td>");
        Response.Write(tab + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
        Response.Write("</Td>");
    }

    Response.Write("</TR>");
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
Response.Write("</font>");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

When i am trying to open the downloaded excel file it showing the following message

[image]

is any changes needed in my code . can you please help out from this.

thanks,   purna

Comment: Note that browsers have settings that allow the client to determine if files of a certain type are opened automatically.  Those settings cannot be overridden by the markup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the file format so I could find how would be the solution in VBA (just writing explicitly the output format)

```
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text1.xlsx'
```

In your code you have to change the following line indicating also explicitly the output format .xlsx:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replay, I have changed my code as you suggested then also i am getting same problem.

Comment: I will try to find more information about this problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the file format. Try below code, it works

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=EmpDetails.xls");
```

instead of

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
```